# How to server static files when using IIS windows server

Tags: iis, iis-8.5, iisnode

I've tried to follow your recommendations in [this answer](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/160#issuecomment-5606547) but I was not able to server static files correctly.
I also took a look at the example in [this post](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2012/05/yaml-configuration-support-in-iisnode.html) and even at [this  gists](https://gist.github.com/pbaio/f63918181d8d7f8ee1d2) which is more complete.

Might it be because of this rewrite rule I'm using?

```
 <match url="/*" />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="bin/www" />
```

This allows me to access to my app like this:

> https://localhost/node/action

Rather than this:

> https://localhost/node/myapp/action

I'm using the Virtual Directory name as if it was the app name.

This is my current `web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="virtualDirPath" value="/node" />
    </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="bin/www" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="StaticContent">
           <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <rule name="DynamicContent">  
            <conditions> 
                <add input="{{REQUEST_FILENAME}}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>  
            </conditions>  
            <match url="/*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="bin/www" />
         </rule> 
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

 <iisnode      
      node_env="localhost"
      nodeProcessCountPerApplication="1"
      maxConcurrentRequestsPerProcess="1024"
      maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry="100"
      namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay="250"      
      maxNamedPipeConnectionPoolSize="512"
      maxNamedPipePooledConnectionAge="30000"
      asyncCompletionThreadCount="0"
      initialRequestBufferSize="4096"
      maxRequestBufferSize="65536"
      watchedFiles="*.js;iisnode.yml"
      uncFileChangesPollingInterval="5000"      
      gracefulShutdownTimeout="60000"
      loggingEnabled="true"
      logDirectory="iisnode"
      debuggingEnabled="true"
      debugHeaderEnabled="false"
      debuggerPortRange="5058-6058"
      debuggerPathSegment="debug"
      maxLogFileSizeInKB="128"
      maxTotalLogFileSizeInKB="1024"
      maxLogFiles="20"
      devErrorsEnabled="false"
      flushResponse="false"      
      enableXFF="false"
      promoteServerVars=""
      configOverrides="iisnode.yml"
     />

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like javascript. Are you sure you're trying to serve files using node? Or are you trying to serve files using IIS windows server? Because the node server frameworks have static file serving built in.

Comment: web.config? Of course that's not JS, that's a IIS config file.

Comment: And yeah, I know node.js can serve them, but when using IIS with iisnode IIS provides a better performance serving them and to be  honest, not quite sure if there's any other alternative anyway.